# In Spyder having to click on the console before responding to an input prompt

Tags: python, input, console, spyder

Is there any way to make it so that I can press run and start typing the answer to  the `input` prompt? It doesn't affect anything else, it's just really annoying having to take my hand off the keyboard every time

Comment: Do you want to automate them?

Comment: @PetIbaño no I just want to click f5 to start the program and begin typing a response to the input prompt without having to touch the mouse

Answer (score 0):

If you run your code using cells (which allow you to break your file in sections by using comments of the form `#%%`) then you can go to

```
Preferences > Editor > Advanced settings > Maintain focus in the Editor after running cells or selections
```

and deactivate that option to get the behavior you want.

Comment: This feature/option does not work in Spyder 3.1.2 (at least on my windows 7 x64)

Comment: I tried in Spyder 4.1.4 but it doesn't work. Also, the option has been moved to: `Tools > Preferences > Editor > **Run code** > Maintain focus in the Editor after running cells or selections`